# Convert a list to String in kotlinx.serialization

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I want to convert a list of a model that I've defined to String for saving it in Database I know how to do that in Gson but I want to do the same in kotlinx.serialization

Convert a list of a model to String In Gson:

```
val gson = Gson()
return gson.toJson(data)
```

Convert the String to the model in Gson:

```
val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
return Gson().fromJson(string, listType)
```

How can I do that in kotlinx.serialization?

Comment: It's documented in the kotlix.serialization [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/builtin-classes.md#lists)

Comment: And note that's not all the documentation, which is extensive: [Kotlin Serialization Guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md).

Answer (score -1):

We can use the following method to encodeToString

```
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString

// extension
fun Any.encodeToString() = Json.encodeToString(this)
```

Use

```
val lis = listOf("1","2")
lis.encodeToString()
```

NOTE: Make sure the custom object needs to encode mark as @Serializable

Comment: not working: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.
also not found way to serialize list even if serializer provided : Serializer for class 'ArrayList' is not found.